# Change component prop through css hover in react-materialui

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to change the noWrap property of a Typography element upon hover. I have declared a custom CSS class for the parent element and the hover does work. But I have no idea how to alter the noWrap property through CSS now.

I have tried this (the hover works):

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    paper: {
      padding: theme.spacing(2),
      "&:hover .questionText": {
        noWrap: true
      }
    }
}));
```

And my JSX:

```js
return(
<Paper className={classes.paper}>
 <Typography className="questionText" noWrap={false} gutterBottom variant="body2">test</Typography>
</Paper>);
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ozrix, I have solved my problem with the following:

```js
const [wrap, setWrap] = useState(false);
```

and

```js
<Paper className={classes.paper} onMouseEnter={() => {setWrap(true)}} onMouseLeave={() => {setWrap(false)}}>
 <Typography noWrap={wrap} gutterBottom variant="body2">
</Paper>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd toggle the boolean flag for your noWrap attribute via setState (or state hooks) using a js mouseover. Something like -

```js
const [ wrap, setWrap ] = useState(false);

function toggleWrap() {
  setWrap(!wrap);
}

return(
  <Paper ...>
    <Typography noWrap={wrap} onMouseOver={()=>toggleWrap()} ... />
  </Paper>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `noWrap={true}` props in `Typography` will apply `white-space: nowrap` styles to your component. This is how you do it using jss:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    paper: {
      padding: theme.spacing(2),
      "&:hover .questionText": {
        whiteSpace: "nowrap",
      }
    }
}));
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 66968582/change-component-prop-through-css-hover-in-react-materialui]

Comment: Thanks for the answer and demo. Is there a way I can prevent the overflow (as seen in the demo)? The text isn't supposed to exceed the box, it should rather end with three dots (...).

Comment: See css [text-overflow](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp). Updated the live demo for you @Dovosi22